# TikZ: Shading a stripped ball

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have a stripped ball with 3-D shading. My attempt

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color=green!60] (0,2) arc (90:-90:2) arc (-90:90:1.2 and 2);
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color=red!60] (0,2) arc (90:-90:-2 and 2) arc (-90:90:-1 and 2);
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue!60] (0,2) arc (90:-90:-1 and 2) arc (-90:90:1.2 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

obviously has a big flaw:

[image]

I would need to make the position of the light spot the same for all three segments. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=green!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\clip (0,2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, x radius=-2, y radius=2] arc[start angle=-90, end angle=90, x radius=1.2, y radius=2];
\shade[ball color=red!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\clip (0,2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, x radius=-1, y radius=2] arc[start angle=-90, end angle=90, x radius=1.2, y radius=2];
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tricolored ball]